# How to prevent chromatic aberration (green/purple fringing) on an After Effects export?

Tags: after-effects, encoding, adobe-media-encoder

I'm relatively new to After Effects. I'm building a short ad using a free template I downloaded. I then rendered the project using Adobe Media Encoder on the H.264 Youtube 1080p setting.

Unfortunately, I'm getting green and purple lines both on the left and right of the overall video, and along any high contrast edge within the video (particularly egregious with any letters). All the animated typography etc. is done within After Effects so there's no question of this being introduced from any of source materials like imported video clips etc.

I've attached a few different images showing this. Any ideas on what I can do to prevent this? A different codec, different settings in Adobe Media Encoder? Could it be a particular filter or color treatments within After Effects itself?

Screengrabs:[image: Right edge][image: Letter borders]

The effect makes the video hazy and adds an unappetizing tint to the borders of all the elements in the video :(.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is not an effect that is intentionally added by the template to yield a retro effect? Some movies do this, for example [Kung Fury](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bS5P_LAqiVg). If it is not, it could be caused by faulty sequence, render or export settings (in particular chroma subsampling or anamorphic pixels). I suggest you post screenshots of those settings so we can see what could be the problem.

Comment: Agreed, chromatic aberration is a defect caused by the physics of glass lenses, to get it on a CG render you have to put it there.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your images for some reason but I suppose this is intentionally added in the template project. To remove it you would of course need to figure out which effect within AE is creating this problem, which I can not do without looking at the file... however I would look for effects like "Optics Compensation" or "Transform" (the effect, not the property). Try turning off any adjustment layers one-by-one to see if that does it. There's a 99% chance that it is an effect on an adjustment layer at the top of your composition creating something like that!